# Dynamically building object key inside square brackets not working

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to dynamically build an object key using an enum value:

```
getRoleNaming(role: Exclude<Role, 'group-admin'>) {
  return this.currentGroup?.[`${role}Naming`];
}
```

Even though all keys of `${role}Naming` are a know key of the currentGroup object, I get the following Error:

"No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'GroupResponse'."

This technically make senses, but the weird thing is that if I write the code like this:

```
getRoleNaming(role: Exclude<Role, 'group-admin'>) {
  const namingKey: keyof GroupResponse = `${role}Naming`;
  return this.currentGroup?.[namingKey];
}
```

it works.

Typescript seems to be intelligent enough to understand those dynamically built keys, so why doesn't it work in the example above?
Can anyone tell me what the difference is between the two?

Comment: Could you please provide a full working example?

Comment: I can't reproduce this: https://tsplay.dev/WG60Xm